# Error in configuration process, Project files may be invalid

Tags: vtk, cmake-gui

I'm new to CMake. I copied a small vtk example from the link  http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/SimplePointsReader  and used CMake to compile. And it gives me an error, " Error in configuration process, Project files may be invalid".

It shows me the errors,

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):   By not providing
>   "FindVTK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked CMake to
>   find a package configuration file provided by "VTK", but   CMake did
>   not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "VTK" with
>   any of   the following names:
>
> ```
> VTKConfig.cmake
> vtk-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "VTK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "VTK_DIR"   to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "VTK" provides a   separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
>   been installed.

I have already installed vtk in my pc and please help me with this problem.

CMakeLists.txt contains the following code

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(SimplePointsReader)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(SimplePointsReader MACOSX_BUNDLE SimplePointsReader)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(SimplePointsReader ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(SimplePointsReader vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

Comment: Well, I found the answer by myself. All you have to do is, add an extra line to the CMakeLists.txt file. Examples are given in the following link,
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.vtk.user/79608

Comment: The link is dead, could you elaborate more on the CMakeLists.txt file ?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by setting **VTK_DIR=path_to_VTK/bin** as an environment variable, because CMakeList.txt file's changing was not helpful.